# Error in DbContext after adding a column to table (ASP.NET/EF Core)

Tags: model, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

All was working fine until I added a new column to my table. I could not find how to update the model class, so I added the column myself in model. But now, when I run my application, I get error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

During debug, I found that it is the problem with creation of instance of my dbcontext:

```
MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext(db);
```

The context object is Not fetching rows from table and is giving this Object reference error.

If I remove the new column from Model class then it works fine. That suggests that my database and model is Not in sync and it seems that the application is using old table design.

I am also trying to use CLI commands to update database but facing difficulties in that as well.

Can anyone suggest how to make model class and table design in sync once a table column is added? I am using ASP.NET Core and EF Core.

Thank you.

Comment: You should only scaffold once and then always use the code first approach (change model in code and run migration + db update) and never change the columns yourself in DB

Comment: Does that mean that I drop the column now and then add in my model class and then run migration? how to run migration + db update then? Please let me know.

Comment: I am trying to use command: dotnet ef database update -c MyDbContext But it is giving me error 'Value cannot be null Parameter name: connectionString'

Comment: Is your DbContext in an class library (i.e. not in the main application which generates the executable)? Then look at the docs on how to work around that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#preview-2-known-issues

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. The property which I had added to the class file was int and the column in the table was also int. But I didn't mention in the class file that it was a nullable property by doing int? . The values in the table were all Null and since the property was Not a nullable property, it caused the issue.

So, we can go ahead and add a new column in table and a matching property in class file. This is Not an issue. Just need to make sure the datatypes (with nullable) are matching.

Answer (score 0):

put try catch to find the exact problem.

This problem occurs because of the difference between schema of database and changed schema at code level. you need to add this line.

```
Database.SetInitializer<yourDbName>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<yourDbName>());
```

It will synchronize your database.